# Redis Timeseries purge data by label

Tags: redis, time-series

I want to cache timeseries data stored in mysql.
For cache stategy I use next logic: split all data to a blocks by one hour, then when user request data I try to range from it from redis, then for all blocks that do not contain in result load a block from mysql db and push it to redis timeseries, if no data exist by this block - push single empty value at the end of block.

Problem: My algorithm implies that if at least one value selected for block therefore all block were chached. The problem occurs when redis reached memory limit and purge data.

Question: Can I specify purge strategy that guarantee if one value of block were purged then all data from block were purged?

I didn't find any solution.

Comment: Did you check the RedisTimeSeries module for Redis? https://redis.io/docs/stack/timeseries/

Comment: Yes, I use this module. And question about this module.